# How can I link a JS script to my header file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to add a JS script with jQuery to the header file in Wordpress. It's function is to darken the background of an element representing a page everytime someone clicks on it.

I've tried adding it with plugins and via `functions.php` file. Neither way worked. I inserted a code into `functions.php` on my child theme which caused my page to not work at all, even after removing the code, so I had to recover the site with a backup. After that I added a fuction with `wp_enqueue_script` which didn't work either.
Luckily after removing the code my site worked again. I didn't add it via `header.php` file itself because I read that it might cause problems for the website.

So my question is: **Is there any way to link a JS script to header.php?** Maybe without using `functions.php`?

**Edit**: Added the code used for `functions.php`

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
```

I replaced `get_template_directory_uri()` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` since I'm adding this to a child theme. I got it from this tutorial: https://www.collectiveray.com/wp/tips/add-javascript-to-wordpress

Comment: You are suppose to do it in `functions.php`. Thats the wordpress standard way of doing it.

Comment: Using functions.php is the correct way. You'd have a more useful response to this question if you showed us the PHP code you tried to use that didn't work so that we can help you debug it.

Comment: will the added code not disappear after an update if writing it directly in functions.php like other changes to a parent theme?

Comment: its better you look into wordpress enqueue codex before posting the query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use functions.php file of your child theme to prevent an update overwriting your changes.

Answering your question, `wp_enqueue_script` - look at the 5th argument `$in_footer`, it must be set to `true`, thus your script will be loaded in header.

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

Comment: I added and set it to `true`, but I got the same "The site is experiencing technical difficulties." error like I'm getting when inserting other code into `functions.php`. Thank you though

Comment: Please check your website configuration, `wp-config.php` file and /or contact hosting support, because I think there is something else involved here.

Comment: I have no host, this is a test website I made. What should I check `wp-config.php` for?

Comment: Could you try and disable plugins one by one and check if the error still persist? What version of wordpress are you using? What parent theme are you using?

Comment: The only plugin installed is classic editor. The error is still there. I also have the latest version (5.2.1) and the parent theme is twenty twelve.

Comment: And if you comment out `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');` what happens?